# How to package a C library with dependencies to swift package

Tags: ios, c, swift, swift-package-manager, wolfssl

I have a C library that contains other C library (WolfSSL, nanopb) dependencies.

I want to (ideally) build a swift package that contains my code referencing the main C library. I would then be able to distribute this package for others to integrate my library into their code.

There is a lot of information between using SPM, XCFramework, and other avenues but nothing that points to the scenario that I am trying to work with.

Is there a standardized way of accomplishing what I want?